# Exchange an element in a js array by index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of URLs ie,

```
var list = [
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/1",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/2",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/3",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/2",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/1",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/2",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/2",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/2",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/2",
];
```

I use a function:
`list.splice(firstIndex, 1, list.splice(secondIndex, 1, list[firstIndex])[0]);`

to exchange an element in firstIndex by element in secondIndex.

This ain't work since the array has duplicate elements, Please suggest an efficient method that uses only index for the operation.
suppose we exchange 5th element with 4th element it will exchange 0th element and will be replaced.
detailed explanation of the question:

consider the array render to an array of images :
[image]

by my method, if 5th elephant is dragged and dropped on 4th bird it will exchange with 1st elephant because the image URL that returned in second part of my equation ie `list.splice(secondIndex, 1, list[firstIndex])[0]` is same for 1st elephant and 5th elephant. Is there a method to do this by splicing array

Comment: If i'm not missing anything, this should do the work `list[1] = list[2]`.

Comment: your code is confusing.  you do understand that splice returns the removed elements right?

Comment: sorry I need to exchange items not replace, I edited

Comment: x=list[1];list[1]=list[2];list[2]=x

Comment: Imagine these are rendered to images  and I drag and drop like a slide show timeline, In that case, when 5th element is dragged and dropped on 4th element, by this code it will replaced by 1st (since `list.splice(secondIndex, 1, list[firstIndex])[0]` return an element)

Comment: can you provide input and desired output that clearly shows what you are trying to achieve, and try to include "edge cases" that need to be dealt with?  I'm having trouble picturing what you are trying to achieve, and what appears to be the edge case of "duplicate items" means

Comment: @VishnuPrasad Are you sure about that? The provided code should work. I believe that the values of `firstIndex` and `secondIndex` are wrong. You might be using `list.indexOf("...")` to find them in which case they are assigned to the first match found.

Comment: hm, maybe he wants all occurrences replaced?  that would be a really odd requirement

Answer (score 0):

Using objects allows changing the url by reference, so it updates for all array elements referencing the same object.  Maps strings to {url} objects, and uses a map to make sure all duplicate strings point to the same object, so they can be updated together.
Then you can just swap the values of the .url property in each list element.

```js
var list = [
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/1",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/2",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/3",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/2",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/1",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/2",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/2",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/2",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/2",
];

var urls = {}; // map to keep track of duplicates
list = list.map(url=>urls[url]=urls[url]||{url}); // map list strings to {url} objects

// swap .url values
function swap(list, firstIndex, secondIndex) {
  [list[secondIndex].url,list[firstIndex].url]=[list[firstIndex].url,list[secondIndex].url];
  return list;
}

console.log(list.map(({url})=>url)
                .map(url=>url.slice(-1)).join(','));
console.log(`${" ".repeat(4*2)}^ ^`);
console.log(swap(list, 5, 4).map(({url})=>url) // map back to list of strings
          .map(url=>url.slice(-1)).join(',')); //format as easy to read list of numbers
console.log(`  ^ ^`);
console.log(swap(list, 1, 2).map(({url})=>url) // map back to list of strings
          .map(url=>url.slice(-1)).join(',')); //format as easy to read list of numbers
```

Comment: just want to mention I approved it, because it doesn't matter, but -1 should never occur

Comment: added two other swap methods.  if you just want something shorter without adding new variables to the scope, you can just use the destructuring method.  I added splice method too.  I'll be honest though, I don't really see much benefit to using those.  especially the splice version

Comment: sorry for the delay, I edited the question for more understanding, I will surely accept and upvote the answer. No hesitation for endorsements :) thank you again.

Comment: note that you cannot use splicing with this, because you are manipulating the property values inside the object, not the refernce to the object stored in the array, but it doesn't really make sense to use splicing anyways